# geom_abline legend - How can I add abline text legend

Tags: r

I'm trying to build charts control. I want to explicit that green line (abline1) is central line and red line (abline2 and abline3) are the limits control.

Can you help me?

```
library(ggplot2)

amostra <- rnorm(30, 10)

qplot(y = amostra, x = seq_along(amostra), ylim = c(5,15), main = "Gráfico de Controle", xlab = 'Período', ylab = 'Valores') + geom_line() +
geom_abline(aes(slope=0, intercept=10), colour = 'green', size=1) +
geom_abline(aes(slope=0, intercept=7), colour='red', size = 1) +
geom_abline(aes(slope=0, intercept=13), colour='red', size = 1) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a legend, then you need an aesthetic mapping. Move color in the `aes()` and add a `scale_color_identity()`. You can do this with

```
qplot(y = amostra, x = seq_along(amostra), ylim = c(5,15), main = "Gráfico de Controle", xlab = 'Período', ylab = 'Valores') + geom_line() +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=0, intercept=10, colour = 'green'), size=1) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=0, intercept=7, colour='red'), size = 1) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=0, intercept=13, colour='red'), size = 1) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_color_identity(labels=c("central","limits"), guide="legend")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather bad hack, but to force the lines to be in the legend, you could try to draw them using the `geom_errorbarh()` function. This will plot errorbars. If you make them as wide as the plot while setting the plot width explicitly with `scale_x_continuous()`, you can have horizontal bars that are shown in figure legend.